# How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ objects?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I didn't receive an answer on [Mathematics S.E.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2372/1012658) at the time of posting. So I cross posted here.

---

How can I find the number of *k*-permutations of $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ objects? $r_x$ implies that there are *x* types of objects.

Here is an example with $k = 15, r_1 = 4, r_2 = 5, r_3 = 8, r_4 = 3$.

> I have 20 letters from the alphabet. There are some duplicates - 4 of them are *a*, 5 of them are *b*, 8 of them are *c*, and 3 are *d*. How many unique 15-letter permutations can I make?

Comment: General formula here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114654/permutations-of-subsets-of-a-multiset?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sketch of an idea. Consider first the problem of computing the number of permutations of $k$ elements *given* the number of elements $n_i$ in each class. This is easy: it works out to $$\frac{k!}{\Pi_i n_i !}$$
because in any fixed string, you can permute the elements in a class without changing the string.

Now consider the problem of writing down the different partitions of $k$ into the sum of $x$ *labelled* numbers. Merely finding the sum itself  can be done by determining the coefficient of $y^k$ in the polynomial 
$$ \Pi_i \frac{y^{r_i+1}-1}{y-1}$$

But this is not enough, since you need to weight each such partition by a different number. However, we know that the contribution of $y^i$ must be $1/i!$, so the overall number we are looking for is $k!$ times the coefficient of $y^k$ in the polynomial 
$$ \Pi_i \sum_{j=0}^{r_i} \frac{y^j}{j!}$$

Answer (score 0):

To make your question more readable, I define variables with the same letter as each mathematical object's first letter. Your question becomes : how to find $p$ permutations of $t_1, t_2,  \cdots, t_{k - 1}, t_k$ things. $t_k$  entails $k$ kinds of $t$ things.

To deduce the formula for all the unique permutations of length $\color{red}{L}$ of $\{t_1,t_2,...,t_k\}$, we must find all combinations  $=\{c_1,c_2,...,c_k\}$ where $0 \leq c_k \leq t_k$, such that
$
\color{red}{c_1 + \cdots + c_k = L}
$.

What we need, is  the product of the factorials of the elements of that combination:
$
\color{limegreen}{\prod_{i=1}^k c_i!}
$

Define the number of combinations as $J$. In closing, to answer your question,  the number of permutations is
$$
= \sum_{j=1}^J \frac{\color{red}{L}!}{\color{limegreen}{\prod_{i=1}^k c_i!}}
= \sum_{\color{red}{c_1 + \cdots + c_n = L}} \binom{\color{red}{L}}{c_1,c_2, \cdots, c_n},
$$

as a  closed form expression with a Multinomial Coefficient. *QED.*

#### Remark

Originally, OP worded this question too [verbosely](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-pleonasm-periphrasis-verbosity-and-tautology) as follows.

> How can I find the number of *k*-permutations of *n* objects, where there are *x* types of objects, and $r_1, r_2, r_3 ... r_x$ give the number of each type of object?

But it's [pleonastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm) to moot $n$ at all, because $n \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + \cdots + r_x.$

"where there are *x* types of objects" is redundant too! $r_x$ itself entails $x$  types, because by definition, $r_x$ means $x$ types of $r$ objects.